# Rotate an array using LINQ syntax

Tags: c#, linq, arrays, rotation

I am solving this problem of rotating an array and got algorithm and code working

```
 int[] Rotate(int[] ar,int k)
        {
            if (k <= 0 || k > ar.Length - 1)
                return ar;
            Reverse(ar, 0, k - 1);
            Reverse(ar, k, ar.Length - 1);
            Reverse(ar, 0, ar.Length - 1);
            return ar;            
        }

 void Reverse(int[] ar,int start, int end)
        {
            while (start < end)
            {
                int temp = ar[start];
                ar[start] = ar[end];
                ar[end] = temp;
                start++;
                end--;
            }
        }
```

Now I want to do this in LINQ and I got the below code, I think this can be done much better.

```
 int[] Rotate(int[] ar,int k)
    {
        if (k <= 0 || k > ar.Length - 1)
            return ar;
        int[] ar1=ar.Take(k-1).Reverse().ToArray();
        int[] ar2=ar.Skip(k - 1).Take(ar.Length - k+1).Reverse().ToArray();
        int[] ar3 = ar1.Concat(ar2).Reverse().ToArray();
        return ar3;
    }
```

This is a well known algorithm from Programming pearls - http://books.google.com/books?id=kse_7qbWbjsC&lpg=PA14&ots=DfzTzQCSar&dq=rotate%20an%20array%20programming%20pearls&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q&f=false

And in general how to develop my LINQ skills, if I am given a programming problem, right now I am only thinking in for loops or foreach loops, how to think in terms of linq operators. I am reading C# 4.0 nutshell, other than practicing any advice?

Comment: This is *extension method* syntax. LINQ syntax would start with `from ...`.

Comment: Yes, but using LINQ to refer to lambdas/Enumerable...I fear that cat is well out of the bag. :(

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, what you're referring to is called the *query comprehension syntax*. There is no such thing as "LINQ syntax".

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos - those extension methods are in the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you for pointing that out; I stand corrected. I always thought LINQ applied specifically to query syntax, but reading up on MSDN indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your code:

```
int[] ar1=ar.Take(k-1).Reverse().ToArray(); 
int[] ar2=ar.Skip(k - 1).Take(ar.Length - k+1).Reverse().ToArray(); 
int[] ar3 = ar1.Concat(ar2).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Since you just want to get all of the remaining elements, the Take in the second line isn't needed.

ar1 and ar2 are just enumerated, so they don't need to be arrays.  The ToArray calls aren't needed.  With a bit of creative renaming thrown in, we have:

```
IEnumerable<int> revFirst = ar.Take(k-1).Reverse(); 
IEnumerable<int> revLast = ar.Skip(k-1).Reverse(); 
int[] ar3 = revFirst.Concat(revLast).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Now we have

rev ( rev(first) + rev(last) )

distributing the outer rev gives

rev ( rev(last) ) + rev ( rev(first) )

which is the same as

```
last + first
```

applying the same operations to the code gives

```
IEnumerable<int> first = ar.Take(k-1); 
IEnumerable<int> last = ar.Skip(k-1); 
int[] ar3 = last.Concat(first).ToArray();
```

which further simplifies to

```
int[] ar3 = ar.Skip(k-1).Concat(ar.Take(k-1)).ToArray();
```

and now we have Jon Skeet's answer so we must be done.

Comment: I love that you know you're done when your answer matches Jon's.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! Thanks for going over my answer and Jon's answer and deriving his from mine, great effort!

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure why you've got all the reversals, to be honest. How about this:

```
int[] Rotate(int[] ar,int k)
{
    if (k <= 0 || k > ar.Length - 1)
        return ar;
    return ar.Skip(k)            // Start with the last elements
             .Concat(ar.Take(k)) // Then the first elements
             .ToArray();         // Then make it an array
}
```

Here's a short but complete program to demonstrate it:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static int[] Rotate(int[] ar,int k)
    {
        if (k <= 0 || k > ar.Length - 1)
            return ar;
        return ar.Skip(k)            // Start with the last elements
                 .Concat(ar.Take(k)) // Then the first elements
                 .ToArray();         // Then make it an array
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] rotated = Rotate(values, 3);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", rotated));
    }
}
```

Output: 4, 5, 1, 2, 3

EDIT: I've just noticed one major difference between my code and your original: yours modifies the original array - mine returns a *new* array with the rotated values. So would your LINQ code, but it means if you were testing my code with something that only looked at the original array, you wouldn't see the rotation.

LINQ is designed to work this way in general - it favours returning a new sequence over modifying an existing one.

Comment: This is not rotating the array for me, its just returning the original array. Just checked in the IDE.

Comment: @satyajit: Then you're not using it properly. I'll add a short but complete program to show it working.

Comment: Yeah I now understood that your code is returning a new array. Thanks for taking time to explain to me!

Comment: With a Rotateleft extension method I was able to write a little 2D rotate: `ar.RotateLeft(up).Select(row => row.RotateLeft(left).ToArray()).ToArray()` so much nicer than the non linq version I wrote.

Answer (score -1):

this is my solution

```
public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
        // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
        if (A.Length <= 1)
        {
            return A;
        }
        var rotate = K % A.Length;

        var leftSide = A.Length - rotate;
        var arr1 = A.AsParallel().Skip(leftSide).Take(rotate);
        var arr2 = A.AsParallel().Take(leftSide);

        return arr1.Concat(arr2).ToArray();
}
```

you can check my [github](https://github.com/mhamri/codility/blob/master/StoneTower.Test/Learning/Lesson2/Lesson2Solution.cs). I also have some unit tests for other cases and other codidlity lessons and challenges