# Rotating an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to rotate an array such that given a number and an array, rotate the array by that amount. IE:

abcdefgh

given 3:

fghabcde

What is the best way to do this without using additional data structures/minimal space?

Here is a function header:

```
public static char[] rotateString(char[] s, int rotateAmount){

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is really all that language agnostic. A C answer would look very different from a Haskell answer.

Comment: "without additional data structures", ie I can't copy the elements to build a new array?

Comment: can we put it back to language-agnostic? :) I like the question, but I haven't done java in years.

Comment: Generally in a question like this you would provide an example method header, for example "I want the method to be `void rotate(char[] array, int number)`, modifying the `array` parameter in-place, and the implementation should not call `new`".

Comment: Sorry jb I'm not so good with other languages :(.

Comment: `String`s are immutable, so you need at least one other data structure (the new `String`).

Comment: You're right. My bad, I changed the input to char[].

Comment: The output should be either `char[]` (to return the input) or `void` (change the input in-place). As it is you still need to allocate a new `String` object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640167/rotate-an-array-using-linq-syntax using C# linq

Comment: I tried to answer this question in due detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17119000/2383578 Please let me know if it is useful...

Comment: Looking at the answers, I'm surprised there is none that use the arraycopy feature... It would probably be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I will make a big assumption that "better" means "I do not want any/as few new data structures".

If this is the case, then the simplest solution is the best, since I don't need to bother optimising by time. I know that the other solutions are much more elegant, I've only posted it because I've read the question as "make sure it's minimal space-wise".

```
private static String rotate( final char[] a, final int n ) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char tmp = a[a.length-1];
        for(int j = a.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            a[j] = j == 0 ? tmp : a[(j-1+a.length)%a.length];
        }
    }
    return new String(a);
}
```

So I hacked this out pretty quickly. Basically, I'm just doing rotates by lengths of one until I've rotated `n` number of times. To optimise it you probably could take `gcd(n, a.length)`.

Now, since my solution is pretty terrible, I'll also post the following code taken from [here](http://www.leetcode.com/2010/04/rotating-array-in-place.html)

```
void reverse_string(char* str, int left, int right) {
  char* p1 = str + left;
  char* p2 = str + right;
  while (p1 < p2) {
    char temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
    p1++;
    p2--;
  }
}

void rotate(char* str, int k) {
  int n = strlen(str);
  reverse_string(str, 0, n-1);
  reverse_string(str, 0, k-1);
  reverse_string(str, k, n-1);
}
```

This is, what I assume to be a C-style implementation that runs faster than mine, using a basic idea that with three reverses, you can implement an inline shift.

As is said here,

> The trick is to do three reverse operation. One for the entire string, one from index 0 to k-1, and lastly index k to n-1. Magically, this will yield the correct rotated array, without any extra space! (Of course, you need a temporary variable for swapping).

I haven't verified this property on the blog I've linked to, so I will post it with a grain of salt that it would appear to work but I've never tested it myself...

Comment: you actually do not need any tmp variable for swapping if you think about it! ;)

Comment: In C or C++ you should rotate by memory movement. But the question was on java...

Comment: @Gevorg, I'm sure you're right, XOR swaps and other things that I'm bad at remembering vaguely come to mind =P There are much cooler and more efficient ways for swapping things that I don't remember at all ^^'

Comment: @Gangnus, yes, the question is on Java, but it's possible to perform the algorithm that both myself and Louis Wasserman have shown without anything more than one array (I think...?) in Java. (If I'm not mistaken, a quick read of the link Louis posted shows that it uses the same idea found in the blog post I linked to).

Comment: `char a = 'a'; char b = 'b'; a = (char)(a + b); b = (char)(a - b); a = (char)(a - b);` ;)

Comment: A tricky way to swap without tmp variable:
swap(x,y) { x ^= y ^= x ^=y; }

Comment: First code Does not work for empty array. The second is not Java.

Answer (score 3):

The Java implementation of `Collections.rotate(List, int)` can be found [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html#811); it uses only constant overhead, and it's quite clean and easy to understand.  I wouldn't necessarily just call it (although with a wrapper like Guava's [`Chars.asList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html#asList%28char...%29), there would only be a constant overhead), but the algorithm is neat and clean, and you could adapt it easily enough to your needs.

It's `O(n)`, but the reason why isn't quite obvious; most of the work is figuring out why it will never visit any one index more than once.  I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: The author wanted less data structures. But this implementation makes...lots of data structures? I wouldn't say this'd be exactly to what the author wanted...but I'll let him/her decide. Mind, I'm no stellar programmer myself, and I think that implementation's great, it's just it constructs extra structures is all...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I was suggesting borrowing the algorithm, not using it directly.

Comment: Ah. That's fair enough. I was reading through the implementation and I thought I saw it creating new data structures, which was why I commented as I did. Perhaps I may have mis-stated that since the link I provided uses the same/a similar idea. ^^'

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?
It requires O(1) extra storage for `temp`.
Try running this with `shift=1`, to see the idea behind it.

```
public static String rotateString(char[] s, int rotateAmount) {
  int length = s.length;
  int shift = (length - rotateAmount) % length;
  for (int start = 0; start < gcd(length, shift); start++) {
    char temp = s[start];
    for (int i = (start + shift)%length; i != start; i = (i + shift) % length) {
      s[(length + i - shift) % length] = s[i];
    }
    s[(length + start - shift) % length] = temp;
  }
  return new String(s);
}
```

`gcd(a,b)` is the greatest common denominator of `a` and `b`, and can be computed using e.g., [Euclid's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

The time complexity is O(n), where `n` is the length of the array.

Comment: This got an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I did it. I used shift = 3 and length = 8 (the test case the poster provides in the question). I'm not entirely sure what went wrong though...

Comment: Fixed; this time also tested it :)

Comment: Negative integers in all usual languages, including Java, won't make integer division and mod correctly. Have you tested for a negative shift? ... With a prog for gcd, will not it be a too big piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

1. As you have to return a result array, you have to create it anyway.
2. The function should work in both directions and when there is one or more turnarounds - as  turning by number more than the length of the array.

   ```
   public static char[] rotateString(char[] s, int rotateAmount){
       int n=s.length;
       char[] res=new char[n];
       if (n==0) return res;

       int turns=rotateAmount / n;
       int j=((-turns+1)*n+rotateAmount) % n;
       for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
           if(j==n) j=0;
           res[j]=s[i];
           j++;
       }
       return res;
   }
   ```

tested by:

```
    System.out.println("'',+1->"+new String(rotateString("".toCharArray(),+1)));
    System.out.println("123,+1->"+new String(rotateString("123".toCharArray(),+1)));
    System.out.println("123,-1->"+new String(rotateString("123".toCharArray(),-1)));
    System.out.println("123,-5->"+new String(rotateString("123".toCharArray(),-5)));
    System.out.println("123,-6->"+new String(rotateString("123".toCharArray(),-6)));
    System.out.println("123,+6->"+new String(rotateString("123".toCharArray(),+6)));
```

Comment: Your solution **won't compile/work**: 1. res is null when you access it in the for-loop. 2. You are not returning anything :)

Comment: @1337 Thank you for the comment, there were even more errors, foolish me. Now it is tested and OK.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Stack?

Let me explain. When you push abcdefgh to stack it becomes **hgfedcba**

Now Pop one element at a time and prepend the string. lets assume rotation amount is 3.

When you pop first elemnt you get **h**. Since 3 is less than number of characters popped pop one more element and prepend to **h**. So when you pop the next element you get **g**. Prepend **g** to **h**. So it becomes **hg**. Repeat the process for the amount of rotation(here it is 3) hence it becomes **fgh**.

Now Create a new string  and pop the rest of elements from the stack and prepend each character popped. Hence it becomes "**abcd**".

Combine the two strings. which is **fghabcd**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is c# version of it just for reference (you may refer to:http://codingworkout.blogspot.com/2014/07/rotating-array.html for more details):

```
void swap<T>(ref T x, ref T y)
        {
            T t = x;
            x = y;
            y = t;
        }
        void Reverse(int[] a, int start, int end)
        {
            int i = start, j = end;
            while (i < j)
            {
                swap<int>(ref a[i], ref a[j]);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        void Rotate(int[] a, int k)
        {
            a.ThrowIfNull("array");
            k.Throw("k", e => e < 0);
            if (a.Length <= 1)
            {
                return;
            }
            k = k % a.Length;
            this.Reverse(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
            this.Reverse(a, 0, k - 1);
            this.Reverse(a, k, a.Length - 1);
        }
```

**Unit Tests**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void RotateTests()
        {
            int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
            for (int i = 1; i <= a.Length; i++)
            {
                int k = a.Length - i + 1;
                int[] b = new int[a.Length];
                this.Rotate(a, i);
                for(int j = 0;j<b.Length;j++)
                {
                    if(k > a.Length)
                    {
                        k = (k % a.Length);
                    }
                    b[j] = k;
                    k++;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Length;j++ )
                {
                    Assert.IsTrue(a[j] == b[j]);
                }
                this.Rotate(a, a.Length - i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simplier and definitely faster

```
private static String rotate( char[] arrayStr, int K, int N ) {
    int[] my_array = new int[N];
    for(int item = 0; item < N; item++) {
        my_array[(item+K) % N] = arrayStr[item];
    }
    return my_array 
}
```

where K = number of rotation and N = lenght of array

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
public static char[] rotateString(char[] s, int rotateAmount){
    String oldStr=new String(s);
    String newStr=oldStr.substring(oldStr.length()-rotateAmount,oldStr.length())+oldStr.substring(0,oldStr.length()-rotateAmount);
    return newStr.toCharArray();
}
```

Comment: The author wanted less data structures. But you've made...lots of data structures? I wouldn't say this'd be exactly to what the author wanted...but I'll let him/her decide.